# Troubleshooting CUBE IDE Compilation Errors

Tags: debugging, compilation, stm32, stm32cubeide

I was making a project with CUBE IDE and I was compiling it on the board, but I got this error when I was compiling a project that I was doing on a new board

No source available for "() at 0xfffffffe

I'm sure they're using the same CPU

It's STM32 ST-LINK, so I can't compile it

The project is also changing well if you modify the code on the existing board, so I don't think the code or MX setting is a problem

```
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOK, GPIO_PIN_2, GPIO_PIN_SET);
```

Even if I create a new project and add the above code, the same error is coming out, so I can't compile it

I want to solve this phenomenon, how can I solve it?

Newly created project code

```
int main(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MPU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/
  MPU_Config();

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOK, GPIO_PIN_2, GPIO_PIN_SET);

  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}
```

The same error is occurring in the simple code as above

---

error image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVUhU.jpg)

Comment: _"the board"_, what board? what exactly is the board or MCU you are working with? _"No source available for "() at 0xfffffffe"_, each error message shown exactly at which line of the source code that the error occured. What if you don't include the line of the code and compile the code without any code other than the auto-generated code by the CubeMX, will it still have the error message? And what is the code above this `HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOK, GPIO_PIN_2, GPIO_PIN_SET);`? Until you could provide those information, no one could magically know what is going with your code.

Comment: The same error occurred when I tried to add only one line of code from the question to the code that was automatically created with the cubeide and only the fan operated

Answer (score 0):

> I was making a project with CUBE IDE and I was compiling it on the
> board, but I got this error when I was compiling a project that I was
> doing on a new board
>
> No source available for "() at 0xfffffffe

It is not a compilation error only something shown during the debugging session.

This error means that you have empty flash, or your vector table is incorrect and the uC went into HF. Most likely reset vector and/or initial stack value was not set.

> You can't erase and debug the STM32 ST-LINK Utility

I do not know why you want to erase or erase this utility.

> Even if I create a new project and add the above code, the same error
> is coming out, so I can't compile it

That error is not related to compilation.

> I want to solve this phenomenon, how can I solve it?

It is not a "phenomenon" only you do something wrong. Show us your code. Hint: It has to be much more that your simple line. I think that you do not compiler anything and you flash the same erratic program to your micro all over again.

> The project is also changing well if you modify the code on the
> existing board, so I don't think the code or MX setting is a problem

I am almost 100% sure that your opinion is not correct.

Comment: You said the reset vector and/or initial stack value is likely not set, so how do I resolve it?